# In 林业、农业、草原、海洋、资源、环境等行业, what industries does 草原 ("grassland") and 海洋 ("ocean") refer to, and why not use 农业 ("agriculture") and 渔业 ("fishing")?

Tags: translation, meaning, word-choice, usage

> **“一箭九星”包含B站视频星**
>
> 记者了解到，本次发射的“吉林一号”高分03-1组卫星由长光卫星有限公司自主研发，包括3颗高分03C视频星和6颗高分03B推扫星，视频星中包括将用于科普的哔哩哔哩视频卫星。该组卫星将与在轨的“吉林一号”卫星组网，为**林业、农业、草原、海洋、资源、环境等行业**用户提供更加丰富的遥感数据和产品服务。
> <sub>[海上飞天！一箭九星！我国首次海上商业化应用发射成功！](http://baijiahao.baidu.com/s?id=1677862386344754467)，2020年09月15日</sub>

I'm confused about the part in bold above, which lists industries: [林业](https://www.mdbg.net/chinese/dictionary?wdqb=%E6%9E%97%E4%B8%9A) = forestry, [农业](https://www.mdbg.net/chinese/dictionary?wdqb=%E5%86%9C%E4%B8%9A) = agriculture, [草原](https://www.mdbg.net/chinese/dictionary?wdqb=%E8%8D%89%E5%8E%9F) = grassland, [海洋](https://www.mdbg.net/chinese/dictionary?wdqb=%E6%B5%B7%E6%B4%8B) = ocean, [资源](https://www.mdbg.net/chinese/dictionary?wdqb=%E8%B5%84%E6%BA%90) = natural resource, and [环境](https://www.mdbg.net/chinese/dictionary?wdqb=%E7%8E%AF%E5%A2%83) = environment.

I don't understand what 草原……行业 ("grassland industry") and 海洋……行业 ("ocean industry") refer to, and why use these terms instead of 农业 and [渔业](https://www.mdbg.net/chinese/dictionary?wdqb=%E6%B8%94%E4%B8%9A) ("fishing industry"), respectively, which (to me) seem more ordinary.

**Question**: In 林业、农业、草原、海洋、资源、环境等行业, what industries does 草原 and 海洋 refer to, and why not use 农业 and 渔业 instead?

Comment: All your points are right. It is just not well written.

Comment: Perhaps the author feels that "草原……行业 ("grassland industry") and 海洋……行业 ("ocean industry"), would give a more generic, broader meaning. 农业 and 渔业, (agriculture & fishing), would be too confining in their applications. Agriculture would just be the planting of crops whereas 草原……行业 would include animal husbandry, and  海洋……行业 would include oyster farming, pearl diving, crabbing, besides just plain commercial fishing. It's like "transport industry" would encompass taxi drivers, bus drivers, pilots, train engineers, etc.  Also 行业, (industry, trade), is wider and general in its meaning than just 业.

Comment: @Wayne Cheah:  perfect answer.  We see the flexibility of Chinese language here. Simple change of one character can easily widen or narrow down your coverage.

Comment: @ Wayne Cheah you should post your comment as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

草原 should mean animal agriculture(畜牧業) and any other nature resources related to grassland.

海洋 have similar concept of 草原.

You could use 農林漁牧業 to indicate agriculture,forestry,fishing and animal agriculture industries.